# Primitive and Induced Dirichlet Characters

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups, dirichlet-character

I'm reading Zagier's book on L-Series and Quadratic Forms and I'm stuck at the proof of the classification of real primitive Dirichlet characters. I understood the proof that $\widehat{(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^*}\cong (\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^*$. Then he says that every Dirichlet character $\chi$ modulo $N=p_1^{n_1}...p_r^{n_r}$ is a product of induced $\chi_i$ Dirichlet characters modulo $p_i^{n_i}$ because $(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^*\cong (\mathbb{Z}/p_1^{n_1}\mathbb{Z})^*\times...\times (\mathbb{Z}/p_r^{n_r}\mathbb{Z})^*$ and he says that $\chi$ is primitive iff all $\chi_i$ are primitive. I understood the second isomorphism however I didn't understand the other arguments. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: In Apostol's book on number theory it is explained in detail.

Comment: @DietrichBurde which one exactly? He has multiple books on number theory

Comment: The one called "Introduction to analytic number theory", Chapter $8$ on Dirichlet characters, induced moduli and primitive characters.

Comment: One way to define primitivity is in terms of the conductor. Define the conductor of a Dirichlet character $\chi$ to be the size of the smallest group $(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^\times)$ that $\chi$ is a character of (the size of the smallest inducing group). Then $\chi$ mod $N$ will have conductor dividing $N$, and will be primitive iff it's equal to $N$. A character factors prime-by-prime, as you note, and so $\chi$ will be primitive iff each prime-power induced character has conductor as large as possible (also, product of chars has conductor = product of conductors).